# whem i am doing model.predict(X_test); it is throwing "NotImplementedError: When subclassing the `Model` class, you should implement a `call` method"

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, transfer-learning

This is my model class. I am trying to implement knowledge distillation [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02531)

```
class Distiller(Model):
    def __init__(self, student, teacher):
        super(Distiller, self).__init__()
        self.teacher = teacher
        self.student = student

    def compile(
        self,
        optimizer,
        metrics,
        student_loss_fn,
        distillation_loss_fn,
        alpha=0.1,
        temperature=3,
    ):
        """ Configure the distiller.

        Args:
            optimizer: Keras optimizer for the student weights
            metrics: Keras metrics for evaluation
            student_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between student
                predictions and ground-truth
            distillation_loss_fn: Loss function of difference between soft
                student predictions and soft teacher predictions
            alpha: weight to student_loss_fn and 1-alpha to distillation_loss_fn
            temperature: Temperature for softening probability distributions.
                Larger temperature gives softer distributions.
        """
        super(Distiller, self).compile(optimizer=optimizer, metrics=metrics)
        self.student_loss_fn = student_loss_fn
        self.distillation_loss_fn = distillation_loss_fn
        self.alpha = alpha
        self.temperature = temperature

    def train_step(self, data):
        # Unpack data
        x, y = data

        # Forward pass of teacher
        teacher_predictions = self.teacher(x, training=False)

        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            # Forward pass of student
            student_predictions = self.student(x, training=True)

            # Compute losses
            student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, student_predictions)

            # Compute scaled distillation loss from https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02531
            # The magnitudes of the gradients produced by the soft targets scale
            # as 1/T^2, multiply them by T^2 when using both hard and soft targets.
            distillation_loss = (
                self.distillation_loss_fn(
                    tf.nn.softmax(teacher_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                    tf.nn.softmax(student_predictions / self.temperature, axis=1),
                )
                * self.temperature**2
            )

            loss = self.alpha * student_loss + (1 - self.alpha) * distillation_loss

        # Compute gradients
        trainable_vars = self.student.trainable_variables
        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, trainable_vars)

        # Update weights
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, trainable_vars))

        # Update the metrics configured in `compile()`.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, student_predictions)

        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update(
            {"student_loss": student_loss, "distillation_loss": distillation_loss}
        )
        return results

    def test_step(self, data):
        # Unpack the data
        x, y = data

        # Compute predictions
        y_prediction = self.student(x, training=False)

        # Calculate the loss
        student_loss = self.student_loss_fn(y, y_prediction)

        # Update the metrics.
        self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_prediction)

        # Return a dict of performance
        results = {m.name: m.result() for m in self.metrics}
        results.update({"student_loss": student_loss})
        return results

    # Initialize and compile distiller
    distiller = Distiller(student=student_model, teacher= model1)
    distiller.compile(
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy'],
        student_loss_fn=CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits= True),
        distillation_loss_fn=KLDivergence(),
        alpha=0.1,
        temperature=40,

)
```

This is how I am training

```
distiller_best_model = SaveBestModel()

'''
teacher_history = teacher_model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=val_generator, steps_per_epoch=batch_size, 
                                    epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[teacher_best_model])
                                    
'''

# Distill teacher to student
distiller_history = distiller.fit(train_generator, 
                                  validation_data=val_generator, 
                                  steps_per_epoch=batch_size, 
                                  epochs=EPOCHS, callbacks=[distiller_best_model])
```

For evaluation purpose, I am doing this and it is working fine

```
distiller.set_weights(distiller_best_model.best_weights)

# Evaluate student on test dataset
distiller_test = distiller.evaluate(test_generator)
```

But I have to make a **Classification Report**. For this I need to do `model.predict(X_test)`
But whenever I am doing this ,

```
distiller.predict(X_test)
```

throwing error as

[image]

Can anyone help me fixing this. Unless I will not be able to make the classification report. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The error message and the documentation both say you should implement a `call()` method when extending `Model`. Maybe you should implement a `call()` method.